# Weird glitch on startup

Tags: 20.04, kernel, oem

I am using Lenovo Legion 5 Pro. I installed ubuntu 20.04 but the software support was not there.

After doing `sudo apt install linux-oem-20.04d` my hardware started working such as wifi and Bluetooth.

But on startup, there is a weird glitch (RGB straight horizontal lines with the screen going black momentarily) on the screen until I enter the password and hit the enter button.
Not sure why this is happening, any help is appreciated!

Comment: Not sure what "weird glitch" means.

Comment: Glitch simply means strings of RGB like a glitch.